# Codeigniter SQL Join query is not returning the data I want

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following query using CodeIgniter.   I want a list that includes a single row for each group and I want the row to inlcude the `liveBlogGroupRecord` status if it is "1".

Right now, I either get only rows for groups that have `liveBlogGroupRecord=1` or, if I comment that line out, I get multiple group rows from the same group since the `blogGroups` table has multiple old values in it that have `liveBlogGroupRecord=0`.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('groups');
$this->db->join('blogGroups', 'groups.groupID = blogGroups.groupID', 'left');
$this->db->where('blogGroups.blogID', $blogID);
$this->db->where('blogGroups.liveBlogGroupRecord', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer this if you show us some sample data, and which rows out of that data you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `SELECT *`. Assuming your `blogGroups` and `groups` tables both have an `id` (or another column that with the same name) only the first one will be returned when you're `JOIN`ing another table.

Selectively choose which columns you need. Try something like this:

```
$this->db->select('groups.*');

/* And more selectively, whichever elements you have from `blogGroups` that you need (I have no idea what those are) */
$this->db->select('blogGroups.name');
$this->db->select('blogGroups.description');
$this->db->select('blogGroups.category');
/* etc */
```

Answer (score 0):

how about adding `$this->db->limit(1);` before `$query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: This will make the entire query return one row.